# Combinatorial Proof to $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {{n}\choose{k}} = 0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question:**
Combinatorial Proof to $$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {{n}\choose{k}} = 0$$

I know that by binomial theorem we can derive this, $$0 = ((-1)+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(-1)^k1^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(-1)^k$$

But as to the combinatorial proof, I'm out of luck. Can anyone give me any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you re-arrange the sum and remember that $n \choose k$ counts the number of subsets of size $k$ of a set of size $n$, then the equality states that for a set with $n$ elements, the number of subsets of even size is equal to the number of subsets of odd size. So, construct a bijection between the set of all subsets $S$ of even size, to the set of all subsets of $S$ of odd size.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint* Think about inclusion exclusion. Alternatively, you can think about the Möbius function of the poset $\wp[n]$.

Comment: Inclusion and Exclusion is still next chapter in this book I'm reading (I happened to glanced at it). Are you referring to the inclusion-exclusion principle such as $|A_1 \cup A_2|  = |A_1| + |A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_2|$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$