# How to Prove the Following Sum is Zero

Tags: summation, proof-writing

How to prove that $\sum_{x=0}^{n}$ $(-1)^x$$ n \choose x$ = $0$. I know there is a connection to the binomial expansion, but I am having difficulty formalizing it with all the notation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternating sum of binomial coefficients: given $n \in \mathbb N$, prove $\sum^n_{k=0}(-1)^k {n \choose k} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611761/alternating-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-given-n-in-mathbb-n-prove-sumn)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/94514/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/879032/42969

Answer (score 7):

$\displaystyle \sum_{x=0}^n {n \choose x}y^x=(1+y)^n$.

Put $y=-1$.